# Entity Framework DbContext Object Disposal

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

Environment : EF 6.0, SQL 2012, WebAPI 2

**Approach 1:using block**

```
  using(MyEntities Test= new MyEntities ())
              {
                     var wareData = Test.WareTypes.ToList(); //Here the actual DBConnect and data fetching happens, i hope i m correct
                     return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<WareType>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, wareData);
                }
```

These scenario applicable irrespective of status of ProxyCreation flag

It fails if i return

- Entire Data Model as such
- Return Entire Data Model and Explicitly
  specifying the entities which needs to be included
- Use DTO and return it without explicit list conversion

It will work one and only if Use

- DTO .. Convert it into List and return it.

Approach 2: without using block

```
 MyEntities Test= new MyEntities ();
           var wareData = Test.WareTypes; //Here the actual DBConnect and data fetching happens, i hope i m correct
           return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<WareType>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, wareData);
```

With this approach, the result will slightly vary with and without ProxyCreation flag.. But only thing is here Object disposal error message not occuring.

**Question:**
**Setup:**

- Proxy Creation Enabled
- Code Enclosed in "Using" block like Approach 1
- Returning entire Data Model and explictly specifiying the entity
  which needs to be included
- Converts the Data to List within using block(To ensure DB operation is done)

**Expected result:**
Self referencing loop(Which i m getting if i dont enclose the code like in Approach 2)
**Actual Output:**
DbContext Object is disposed along with self referencing loop error

**Interested in knowing the explanation for this behaviour....**

***P.S :*** Have working solution .... Question is more in terms of understanding the concept..